# Pod Stuck in Terminating State Due to iptables 'Chain Already Exists' Error in Kubernetes

Tags: iptables, kubernetes, weave

I'm facing an unusual issue with a Kubernetes deployment using the Mailu Helm chart, specifically the `mailu-front` component. After updating the deployment, the newly created pod works fine, but the old pod gets stuck in the 'terminating' state. The Kubernetes event log shows the following error related to pod termination:

```
error killing pod: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "237aa644-7634-4fa2-a538-f973e7f7dfab" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to destroy network for sandbox \"cbbcf6eaaf47c0ef5b92b97187276d04def7bcef3e68b92889b7993ba970ce55\": plugin type=\"portmap\" failed (delete): could not teardown ipv4 dnat: running [/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -N CNI-DN-0e851981d24bd2d807e1a --wait]: exit status 1: iptables: Chain already exists.\n"
```

I'm running a small kubeadm 1.28 cluster with Weave CNI and Debian 11 host OS for all nodes

Attempts to force delete the pod have been unsuccessful. This issue seems to be related to an iptables configuration, specifically a conflict where a chain cannot be torn down because it already exists (conflicting, since the command in the event log intends to create the chain, not delete it).

I've not found much information on how to resolve this particular error.

If I log into the host OS of the affected node and run `sudo iptables -t nat -N CNI-DN-0e851981d24bd2d807e1a --wait` , I can indeed see the issue reflected in the output:

```
iptables: Chain already exists.
```

If I try to delete the chain with `sudo iptables -t nat -X CNI-DN-0e851981d24bd2d807e1a --wait`, iptables says the chain is already in use:

```
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables):  CHAIN_USER_DEL failed (Device or resource busy): chain CNI-DN-0e851981d24bd2d807e1a
```

I tried restarting the node but the problem still occurs.